# How to program async processing of widgets?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading

I have list of files(widgets) that I need to do some work on. I want to do it in async manner so my interface stays responsive. I want to update UI with progress. Here is my prototype code. How do I accomplish this? I assume I need to utilize threading, but I also don't want to span all the threads at the same time, one by one is fine.

```
void Process()
{
    var documents = GetDocuments();
    foreach(document in documents)
    {
        ProcessDocument(
        document,
        status => this.TextBox.Text += status); 
    }
}

void ProcessDocument(Document document, Action<string> onCompleted)
{
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [BackgroundWorker class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx) to process operation asynchronous in Windows Forms projects.

```
BackgroundWorker worker = new BackgroundWorker();
worker.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
worker.DoWork += (sender, args) => {
    var documents = GetDocuments();
    foreach(var document in documents)
    {
        ProcessDocument(document);
        worker.ReportProgress(0, status);
    }
};
worker.ProgressChanged += (sender, args) => {
    this.TextBox.Text += args.UserState.ToString();
};
worker.RunWorkerAsync();
```

Comment: BackgroundWorker is deprecated in favor of Task Based Programming

Comment: @LMB Where have you read that? The MSDN page on BackGroundWorker does not mention this. By the way I agree with you that TPL is the best approach for Frameworks 4 and above.

Comment: @PanosRontogiannis I'll give a try to find the exact page, but I recall it was in MSDN, in one of the pages about Tasks namespace an Task usage.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the **System.Threading.Thread** Class

Remember that you will need to used delegates to safe update the controls on your UI
you cant modify controls when running in other than the main UI thread.

If you want to do it easy without delegates because you think you can control it
 you can set the property

```
Control.CheckForIllegalCrossThreadCalls=false
```

So you will be allowed to update controls without the Illegal Cross Thread check

If you prefer to use the BackgroundWorker class, this allow you to bind and Event called
ProgressChanged that allows you to update UI too

```
public void backgroundWorker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
     //thread work
    }

    // This event handler updates the UI
    private void backgroundWorker_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        // Update the UI here

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Also consider [Reactive Extensions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/gg577609.aspx), particularly `IObservable<T>`.

Answer (score 0):

Framework 4.5 introduced the [async/await](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/hh191443.aspx) keywords that simplify asynchronous .NET programming.

Have a look at [TPL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460717.aspx) if you are using Framework 4.

If on the other you are using earlier versions of .NET (3.5 and older) then you should have a look at [APM](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228963.aspx).